# Reading the contents of a specific line in Python?

Tags: python, file, file-io

Supposing I would like to read the contents of the current line of a file and check if the contents matched an input:

```
keyword = input("Please enter a keyword: ")
file = open('myFile.txt', encoding='utf-8')
for currentLine, line in enumerate(file):
    if currentLine%5 == 2:
        if currentLine == keyword:
            print("Match!")
        else:
            print("No match!")
```

Obviously this does not work because `currentLine`is an integer (the current line number) and `year` is a string. How would I get the contents of the current line? `currentLine.readlines()` didn't work and that's how I thought I would do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `line` as a variable (string that represent each line). Why don't you use it?

```
keyword = input("Please enter a keyword: ")
file = open('myFile.txt', encoding='utf-8')
for currentLine, line in enumerate(file):
    if currentLine % 5 == 2:
        if line.rstrip('\n') == keyword:  # <------
            print("Match!")
        else:
            print("No match!")
```

I used `str.rstrip('\n')` because the iterated lines contain newline.

If you want to check the line contains keyword, use `in` operator instead:

```
if keyword in line:
    ...
```

---

BTW, default start number for `enumerate` is `0`. If you want line number (that start from 1), specify it explicitly: `enumerate(file, 1)`

Comment: Did not know about the enumerate start parameter. Nice!

Comment: ^ Thanks for that bit. I've been subtracting everything by one and now that seems stupid.